# Magento 2: update individual custom option value programmatically

Tags: magento2, customizable-options

I'm using a script to programmatically update some products, bootstrapping Magento. I've had a lot of luck saving attributes using the product repository, when it comes to customizable options, I'm confused about the best way to update existing values.

I'm able to load up all of the options I need to update using `Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Option\CollectionFactory`, but not sure how to save them from there.

Do you have to save option data as an array, or is it possible to update an individual field?

Comment: can you provide some code which you have done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, it ended up making the most sense for us to update the values with a SQL query.

In my script, I added:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
$connection = $resource->getConnection();
$tableName = $resource->getTableName('catalog_product_option_type_value');
$sql = "Update " . $tableName . " Set custom_weight = " . $value . " where option_type_id = " . $valuesArray['option_type_id'] . "\n";
$connection->query($sql);
```

We have a custom_weight field for our options. We needed to update a bunch of values as pulled from a CSV with some logic thrown in there. The $sql assignment and the $connection->query($sql) line occur, in actuality, within a foreach loop.

Answer (score -1):

**At first create an observer with event - catalog_product_save_before
In the observer place the below code -**

```
/** Dependency classes **/
use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductCustomOptionInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\OptionFactory;\
```

public function __construct(
        OptionFactory $productOptionFactory
) {
        $this->productOptionFactory = $productOptionFactory;
}

`$product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
    $exist = false;
    //check if the custom option exists
    foreach ($product->getOptions() as $option) {
        if ($option->getGroupByType() == ProductCustomOptionInterface::OPTION_TYPE_FIELD
            && $option->getTitle() == 'Custom Option') {
            $exist = true;
        }
    }
    if (!$exist) {
        try {
            $optionArray = [
                'title' => 'Custom Option',
                'type' => 'field',
                'is_require' => false,
                'sort_order' => 1,
                'price' => 0,
                'price_type' => 'fixed',
                'sku' => '',
                'max_characters' => 0
            ];
            $option = $this->productOptionFactory->create();
            $option->setProductId($product->getId())
                ->setStoreId($product->getStoreId())
                ->addData($optionArray);
            $product->addOption($option);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            //throw new CouldNotSaveException(__('Something went wrong while saving option.'));
        }
    }`

Comment: Curious, why would an observer be necessary? I'm running a script that bootstraps Magento, so I'm updating the products that way.

Comment: Also, if I'm reading this correctly, this creates options that don't already exist, whereas I'd like to update the values of existing options.